# How can I redirect users with custom request (not folder) to root folder?

Tags: nginx

I need to redirect a facebook ID link (https://example.com/?fbclid=some_gibberish_text) to my root folder. I am using return 301 but gotten no result. Below is my configuration in nginx.conf:

```
location ^~ /?fbclid=(.*) {
    return 301 https://example.com;
}
```

I am kind of new to Nginx. How do I achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Request parameters are not subject to match in `location` blocks. The matching is performed against a normalized URI without the arguments (`?arg1=value1&arg2=value2...`) part. With your example, you are trying to redirect a request from the root folder to the same root folder. Depending on what you really need, you can redirect any request containing `fbclid` argument to the root of your site:

```
if ($arg_fbclid) {
    return 301 https://example.com;
}
```

or, if you want to hide this argument from your backend, just get rid of it:

```
if ($args ~ (.*)(^|&)fbclid=[^&]*(\2|$)&?(.*)) {
    set $args $1$3$4;
}
```

(this complex regex removes the corresponding request argument whether it is at the beginning, in the middle or at the end of the request string).

Put one of these constructions **outside** your `location` blocks.

Comment: @TajamTajam That's ok, so why you did not accept an answer?